# Can I use Django models to preform complex queries on a database?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-database

I want to use django for a database driven app and I want to know if django models permit me to use complex query to fetch data.

I have for example this table inside a database:

[Click to show image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftxIp.png)

I want to extract data resulting from this query.

```
SELECT name
FROM movies
WHERE year between 1995 AND 2001
AND rank between 6 and 9;
```

How can I do it with Django?

Comment: That's not complex at all - it is a simple query in SQL and just as t to express with Django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Movie.objects.filter(year__range(1995, 2001), rank__range(6, 9))`

You can use filters to limit querysets with Django.